# .Import CSV to sqlite3 database

Tags: csv, sqlite

I am absolutely banging my head against the wall because no other answers have worked for me.

I have a CSV file...here are 10 lines of it as an example

```
Row 1:    https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J4813A                  
Row 2:    F.05.80   6-Jul-15    3-Nov-15    Release notes   1.67 MB »
Row 3:    https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J4903A                  
Row 4:     I.10.107 24-Aug-15   2-Nov-15    Release notes   3.49 MB »
Row 5:     https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9019B                 
Row 6:     Q.11.76  6-Feb-17    21-Feb-17   Release notes   2.80 MB »
Row 7:     https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9022A                 
Row 8:     N.11.76  6-Feb-17    21-Feb-17   Release notes   3.11 MB »
Row 9:     https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9147A                 
Row 10:     W.15.14.0015    23-Mar-17   30-Mar-17   Release notes   9.16 MB »
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9eoI.jpg here is a screenshot of the CSV file

I also have a database file created for this express purpose. Its name is Test.db. In that database, there is a table named output

When I run `.schema Output` i get

`CREATETABLE(Output("https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J4813A" TEXT);

I am attempting to use the SQLite command line to resolve this

```
`C:\Windows\System32>sqlite3 c:\source\test.db
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import c:/source/output_file.csv Output`
```

I get this error message
    `c:/source/output_file.csv:59: expected 1 columns but found 6 - extras ignored`
This error occurs on every single line, from 1 to 59

What am i missing here?

Comment: It seems like line 59 of the file would be interesting. Is it one of the ten quoted lines?

Comment: I forgot to mention, i get one of those error messages per line. Starting from line 1, up to 59

Comment: I tried your desription, works for me, with a file in the same folder I should mention. So it would be `.import import.sql toy`.

Comment: Try doing the same thing with a special test file. Simplest test just with one letter per line.

Comment: Show the schema of your table.

Comment: Do you really get the same error for each line? Not only for every other line? Not for each line but with different numbers of too many columns?

Comment: Checkt the content of your input file. Does it really conrtain two differently looking kinds of lines, aleternating? I think it might be continued lines of only one kind. E.g. the `»` is what your editor uses to indicate a continued line. Find an editor which can render non-printable characters. Otherwise copy the content you quoted in your question, write that to the input file and try again, so that you and I are looking at the same thing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/yxX5F - in this pic, you can see whats happening
http://imgur.com/a/6ddg6 - here is a screenshot of my input file. This is taken programmatically from a python script i run. Do you think those >> at the end could be causing a probelM?

Comment: Please repeat what you did as explained here. especially the separator line. Please show your input file with visible whitespace.

Comment: `sqlite3 test.db`

`.separator ,`

`.mode csv`

`.import C:/source/output_file.csv Output`

Comment: Is that one line from the shell? I'd be afraid about quoting, expanding etc. Better do it in the command line tool. In your question it seems that you did everthing from tool prompt.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/V4leS here is the csv with white space

Comment: It is one line per command, i can't figure out line breaks in this damn comment window. I run it from the sqlite command line tool...

Comment: Edit your question for better formatting options. While you are at it add all the information you gave in comments here and also add the info I was asking for.

Comment: I would like to see you input file as text, not as a table. Please open it in a text editor with white space rendering. What is that between date and release?

Comment: I can reproduce your errors if I concat every second line to previous one , replace all white space groups by tabulators and use tabulator as separator. This might explain my questions...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/UxYGD 
This is from Atom

Comment: When you have time, read [mcve]. Please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143534/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-kevin-johnson).

Answer (score 1):

The schema for your table looks broken, probably by misused formatting, but it looks like having only one column.
Your input file in the picture shows that you have many  `,`.
(Your input quote in the question did not show that by the way.)
You are using `,` as separators to fill a table with one column.
I.e. sqlite sees many columns in the import and only has one column to fill.

Make a table with six columns.
Start with a safe one i.e. six columns of varchar(300).

Alternatively, only import one column, by using a separator which does not occur in your input file. That would work with a table which only has one column.

Comment: Show the schema of your table, make sure that it is readable. Try a `.headers on` `select * from output`. I think it will only show one column.

Comment: You are working from sqlite commandline tool, aren't you? Do not allow a GUI to hide relevant information from you.

Comment: I may end up doing something different with my input file. My boss just told me we dont need data in all 6 columns, so im going to change my program to only pull 1... I think importing 1 column should just work... ill keep you updated and close this question if needed

Comment: Can you please show the readable schema of your table before closing? I am kind of stubborn and admit that I want to see that I am right.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here :

The CSV i was using to import over was poorly formatted. I re-created it with 1 column and a specific header field and it worked without issues

Thanks Yunnosch for your guidance

Comment: So importing the csv as only one column into the table which only has one column works? It had only one column all the time?

Comment: No, it started with 6 columns. I re-worked it and got it working with 1 column. Next step is to fix it with 2 columns

Comment: So how does this `CREATETABLE(Output("https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J4813A" TEXT);`make six columns? It is definitly broken, but if anything it makes one column. Also your error messages complain about six columns not fitting into one column. I think your SQLite agrees with my guess of one column.